# Removing motherboard speaker powered on

Tags: motherboard, speakers

I have a stupid question.  Can a PC speaker/beeper be removed while the PC is powered on?  I only have one, and it is in a PC that is running AI training that can't be interrupted.  On the other hand, I have a used (new to me) motherboard that is not giving me a display, and I need a speaker to see if it is giving any POST codes.

Comment: Something is physically holding the speaker in place.  It's generally a bad idea to be poking around the MB with tools while it's running something you can't afford to have interrupted.  Can't you scrounge any other little speaker to use?  But just pulling the speaker's connector shouldn't affect anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove the speaker connector carefully while the PC is on. Just make sure you don't accidentally touch anything else with blank metal contacts etc.

When the speaker is silent, no current is flowing, so it's perfectly safe.

However, it may be more difficult to actually remove the speaker itself, but that really depends on your your chassis. It's possible you can't remove it without having to remove other things you don't want to remove while the computer is running.